# Which version of the New Testament should one buy to study Biblical Greek?

Tags: greek

I'm currently planning to buy material for the study of Biblical Greek, but I'm not aware of the form in which the current Greek New Testament are available. So as for a proper study of Biblical Greek, which version am I recommended to buy?
If possible I'd like to get an interlinear version, but if none is available, I should be fine with another Greek Version.

Comment: Typically this site is devoted to the interpretation of a specific Biblical text. The Greek text depends on the English Bible you would normally use. The KJV has a different Greek text that was used as the basis of the translation -- commonly called the Textus Receptus or Received Text. Most other modern translations are based on the Critical text. Beginning Greek textbooks will work with either Greek version. Ted Hildebrandt has an excellent textbook, workbook and resources for free.  Google Mastering New Testament Greek Ted Hildebrandt to find his site for beginning to advanced Greek.

Comment: @KenBanks, I think your comment has suited, I first thought modern translations were based in some variant of modern Greek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting out with Greek and learning to read it, then I would advise against an interlinear Greek as the English provides a distraction that cannot be ignored.  (Interlinears are VERY useful but not when you are learning.)

Among the countless Greek New Testaments available (almost any will do your purpose) I suggest that you purchase a "Reader's Greek new Testament".  This is an ingenious invention that contains the usual Greek text but includes a selective running dictionary of "rare" words as a footnote on each page.  "Rare" will usually be something like words occurring less that (say) 25, 30 or 40 times in the NT depending on which you buy.  There are several available.  Here is a sample:

https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks-intl-ship&field-keywords=Readers+Greek+New+Testament&rh=i%3Astripbooks-intl-ship%2Ck%3AReaders+Greek+New+Testament

You can purchase either paper or an electronic version ("e-book" or similar).